# How to get bbpress sticky topics

Tags: bbpress, sticky-post, theme-thesis

I want to get bbpress sticky topics using query like this:

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
    rsort( $sticky );
    $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2);
        query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1, 'post_type'=> 'topic' ) );
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
//do something
endwhile;
endif;
```

How can i make query something like this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the query like above using following code.

```
<?php
query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_bbp_sticky_topics',  'post_type'=> 'topic', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        //do something
    endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

But i strongly recommend you not to alter main query using query_posts() and instead use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) as following.

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_bbp_sticky_topics', 'post_type'=> 'topic', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
if ( $query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        //do something
    endwhile;
endif; 
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: @arslaanejaz Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: thanks for you answer but my friend no luck. i m not getting any record.

Comment: but i am heaving this value in wp_postmeta. _bbp_sticky_topics => a:1:{i:0;i:632;}

Comment: Can you shoe me your updated code?

Comment: same as you provided is WP_Query section. called the_title() in //do something

Comment: Have you added any sticky topic? I mean sticky topic and not super sticky topic.

Comment: i found the solution. read my answer, i m working on it from last 6 hours. hope my answer will give you information. thanks a lot for being with me.

Comment: @arslaanejaz That's nice... but do you want to display forum title or topic title?

Answer (score 2):

a better way to to this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $post->ID, 'post_type'=> 'forum', 'meta_key' => '_bbp_sticky_topics' ) );
            if ( $query->have_posts()) : 
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
                    $sticky = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_bbp_sticky_topics' );
                    $sticky = maybe_unserialize( $sticky );                 
                endwhile;
            endif;          
            wp_reset_postdata();
```

Then $sticky will be an array with all of the sticky topics from the current forum you are querying, you could do a second query with `post__in` to show the sticky topic's content, title, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of workaround i found the solution. This code will give you the results and why i will explain:

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2,'post_type'=> 'forum', 'meta_key' => '_bbp_sticky_topics' ) );
if ( $query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        the_title(); echo '<br />'; the_ID(); echo '<br />';
    endwhile;
endif; 
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

the trick is to use `'post_type'=> 'forum'` instead of `'post_type'=> 'topics'`, and it will show you the forums instead of topics because wp_postmeta save data like this `a:1:{i:0;i:632;}` with the **post_id of forum not topics**. Thanks for Vinod Dalvi, he really gave me a direction to solve this issue.

Comment: That's nice... but do you want to display forum title or topic title?

Comment: @Vinod i m displaying forum title for now but i think the same approach is not possible with topic. forums is working so we can extend the functionality to get title.

Comment: Topic is also working at my side. IF you provide me more information about this from your side then we can resolve it.

Comment: @Vinod i tried tens of time and i m not getting any sticky post record by topic. i don't know where the problem was. are you using hierarchical forums? i m using... i really want to approve your answer but for that it should be recommended answer.

Comment: I am not using any hierarchical forums. I have just installed bbpress plugins created some topics and made some of them sticky. Are you following the same steps or different?

Comment: @Vinod  any how i solved my problem, but here story is bit different i m working at a huge site containing my own six plugins and it is also thesis 2 base site.

Comment: ok. It will be useful if you share how you solved the problem.

Comment: @Vinod for explaining how my system is working, i gave my own answer ie i used forum not topic as post type and i m fetching forum name. Its good for me for now. if i proceed i will share more.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you only want to get an array of the super sticky topics (stuck to front), then you can simply use this code:

```
$stickies = get_option( '_bbp_super_sticky_topics', array() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, [from this bbpress.org thread](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/custom-query-to-display-sticky-posts-only/)

`$query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => bbp_get_super_stickies());`